# How to maintain values of variable between multiple action call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, static

I my project I am having varible

```
id=params[:id]
status=params[:status]
.....

if(!status.nil?)
   if(status='off')
   flag[id]=1
   else
   flag[id]=2
   end
else
   if(flag==1)
    puts off
   else
    puts on
end
```

- request come with status depending on status I am creating flag
- i want to use that flag in next call to the function when the status is nil
- My problem is that I am not getting the flag values in next call
- How to temporary store that values for later use

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep a value between requests, using sessions is probably the right way to do it. See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) for more on the topic.